# How to install ant & ivy?

Tags: linux, installation, ant

I've installed ant... and I've installed ivy (both from synaptic), but ant can't find ivy!

When I run ant to build ['october-chess-engine'](https://github.com/skeeto/october-chess-engine/) I get the following:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/zeigfreid/repos/october-chess-engine/build.xml:32: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:resolve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/zeigfreid/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

I'm not sure how to proceed! I checked out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/446496/how-to-install-ant-1-8-on-ubuntu-11-04-properly), but it didn't address my issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How did you install ivy? In any case you need to put ivy.jar (from http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.html) in any of the listed directories

- `/usr/share/ant/lib`
- `${HOME}/.ant/lib` (in your case `/home/zeigfreid/.ant/lib`)

You can check what and is loading if you execute it with the `-v` option (verbose)

Comment: That did it, thanks! I just made a symlink in ${HOME}/.ant/lib to the ivy.jar file.

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be a common issue, as I had the same problem. After installing **ivy** with `apt-get`, it didn't show up in the desired folders, but in:

```
[...]
/usr/share/doc/ivy
/usr/share/doc/ivy/README
/usr/share/doc/ivy/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/ivy/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ivy/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/ivy/copyright
/usr/share/java/ivy-2.2.0.jar
/usr/share/java/ivy.jar
[...]
```

(You may have to update your mlocate database with
`updatedb`
and then use
`locate ivy`
to find it.)

To solve this: create a link in the `/usr/share/ant/lib/`

`sudo ln -s -T /usr/share/java/ivy.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ivy.jar`

Note, that `/usr/share/java/ivy.jar` is a link itself.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Although I get a warning about a 'non-official version'

Answer (score 1):

I found very useful to let ant to install ivy, see [automatically installation](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/install.html).

This way the only operating system dependency is ant, and there is no need to add extra configuration like ANT_OPTS or classpath.