# Ivy installation - ivy.jar in /usr/share/ant/lib not working

Tags: linux, java

I'm trying to get Apache Ivy installed and I've downloaded the binary. Following the question here: [How to install ant & ivy?](https://superuser.com/questions/452192/how-to-install-ant-ivy), and instructions here: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0/install.html I've moved the binary from the download directory as such:

> sudo cp ivy-2.3.0.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ivy.jar

Yet, when I run ant from the hello-ivy example, I still get:

```
apache-ivy-2.3.0/src/example/hello-ivy/build.xml:38: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:retrieve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
```

I have also tried to put it in $HOME/.ant/lib. I've also tried to run like follows:

> ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib

I'm running CentOS6.4 w/ Ant 1.7.1.

It **IS** showing up in my classpath. From ant -diagnostics:

> java.class.path :
>   /usr/share/java/ant.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxp_parser_impl.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-commons-apis.jar:/usr/share/java/antlr.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/java/bcel.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/share/java/bsf.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/share/java/oro.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/share/java/regexp.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-commons-resolver.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/share/java/jakarta-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/jakarta-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/java/javamail.jar:/usr/share/java/jaf.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/share/java/jdepend.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/share/java/jsch.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-nodeps.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxp_transform_impl.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-trax.jar:/usr/share/java/xalan-j2-serializer.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/tools.jar:/home/jteems/.ant/lib/ivy.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:**/usr/share/ant/lib/ivy.jar**:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-nodeps.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-trax.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar

All without success. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to either the version of ant (1.7.1) or the fact that I was using the CentOS/RedHat RPM version. Per the mailing list, http://www.mail-archive.com/ivy-user@ant.apache.org/msg05766.html, there is a known issue with the RPM'd version. I installed the latest version of ant (1.9) on my machine and all worked well.

Comment: I had the same issue, but wasn't certain which way you installed ant again that fixed your issue. In my case, I reinstalled Ivy with the "apache-ivy.noarch" package, which placed Ivy in a different location (/usr/share/java/ivy-2.3.0.jar) and now ant 1.7.1 can find Ivy.