# ln -s -T :: what does the "-T" switch do exactly?

Tags: ln

I've seen the **-T** switch being used, e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/452192/how-to-install-ant-ivy).
Looking at the man page it simply reads: "treat LINK_NAME as a normal file". Can somebody shed some light showing the difference between using and not using the **-T** switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the “Target Directory” chapter in the GNU Coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Target-directory):

> `-T`
> `--no-target-directory`
>
> Do not treat the last operand specially when it is a directory or a symbolic link to a directory. This can help avoid race conditions in programs that operate in a shared area. For example, when the command `mv /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no guarantee that `/tmp/source` was renamed to `/tmp/dest`: it could have been renamed to `/tmp/dest/source` instead, if some other process created `/tmp/dest` as a directory. However, if `mv -T /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no question that `/tmp/source` was renamed to `/tmp/dest`.
>
> In the opposite situation, where you want the last operand to be treated as a directory and want a diagnostic otherwise, you can use the `--target-directory` (`-t`) option.

Note that the GNU project does not consider man pages as a primary form of documentation; you should always look at the corresponding `info` page (the note about this is put at the end of each man page for a program which is developed as part of the GNU project).